# Why does @progress/kendo-angular-notification display messages as plain text?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm executing `show()` like this:

```
this.notificationService.show({
      content: 'Hi! I am string info type notification.',
      animation: { type: 'fade', duration: 500 },
      position: { horizontal: 'right', vertical: 'top' },
      type: { style: 'info', icon: true },
      closable: true
    });
```

And somewhy I get simple text message, not pretty styled notification. It fades as I set. But there are no styles. And positioning is broken.

Comment: Did install one of the Kendo UI themes?

Comment: @R.Richards I've missed one dependency) `ng add` helped